# List Content Types on Strapi

Tags: api, vue.js, routes, strapi

I am building a webapp using Strapi as my back-end. I have no problem retrieving my content. But i really need to list the content type created in my backend. Is there an existing route for that ? Because i can't find one.

I have already try this one :

```
http://localhost:1337/api/content-type-builder/content-types/api::supplier-catalog.supplier-catalog
```

But i am stuck with a 403 Forbidden error.

Maybe, someone already had that problem.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we get all the content type structures and details from strapi using the Rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570631/how-can-we-get-all-the-content-type-structures-and-details-from-strapi-using-the)

Comment: I found the answer to the problem. It wasn't coming from the route but from the access of the token i was using to retrieve the data. But thank you, for the comment